# .NET MVC Route not working propely

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have defined my routes in .NET app like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Register",
        url: "Register",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Register" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Login",
        url: "Login",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login" }
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ResetPwd",
        url: "{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ResetPwd", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

So that I can have routes like following:

```
mysite.com/Login
mysite.com/Register
mysite.com/ResetPwd
```

Now the problem arises with other controller when I try to redirect the user to dashboard when hes logged in successfully from mysite.com/Login like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
```

However I'm getting an error:

> The resource cannot be found.

I presume it want's me to define a route now for dashboard/index... but isn't that nuts since then I'd have to add every route manually ???

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: this controller action is not in routeconfig

Comment: Your `ResetPwd` route means any url containing 2 segments will hit that route (not the `Default` route). You should change that to (say) `url: "ResetPassword/{id}", (or you could add a constraint for the `Id` parameter

Comment: @StephenMuecke ye that works like  a charm, thx a lot mate! =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your resetpassword route to

```
        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "ResetPwd",
          url: "ResetPwd/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ResetPwd", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
```

Currently your provided url `/Dashboard/Index`is looked up by this route with `Dashboard` being an Action on Default `Home` controller which doesn't exists in my opinion.